# Very confused about Cauchy Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Cauchy's Inequality states that, $$ \forall a, b \in R^{n}, |a \cdot b| \leq |a||b| $$. However, the dot product is $$ x \cdot y = x_{1}y_{1}+...+x_{n}y_{n}$$ while the norm of x is $$ |x| = \sqrt[2]{x_{1}^{2} +...+x_{n}^{2}} = \sqrt[2]{x \cdot x}$$. Therefore, $$ |a \cdot b| = \sqrt[2]{(a \cdot b) \cdot (a \cdot b)}$$

How does one calculate $$ (a \cdot b) \cdot (a \cdot b)$$? Since $$ (a \cdot b) \in R^{n} $$ when n = 1, is $$ (a \cdot b) \cdot (a \cdot b) $$ just multiplication of real numbers? (For some reason, I always thought that $$ n \geq 2 $$.)

Comment: In the statement $|a \cdot b| \le |a| |b|$, the bars on the left just mean absolute value of the real number $a \cdot b$. The bars on the right mean norms of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: if $a,b$ are vectors $(a\cdot b)$ is a scalar and $|(a\cdot b)|$ is an "old fashioned" absolute value, and $(a\cdot b)\cdot(a\cdot b)$ is the multiplication of two scalars.  However, $|a|$ is a norm.

Answer (score 1):

$|x|$ for $x \in R^n$ with $n \ge 2$ is a generalization of $|x|$ for $x \in R^1$

Answer (score 0):

With $(a \cdot b) \color{red}{\cdot} (a \cdot b)$ is meant that $\cdot$ is the dot product and that $\color{red}{\cdot}$ is multiplication.

It helps to use distinguishable notation, so use for example $\langle a,b\rangle $ for dot products and $a_1\cdot b_1$ for multiplication.

Comment: It's better just to omit the multiplication symbol most of the time for multiplication of real numbers!! In elementary courses, I put vector symbols on my vectors (or boldface in print) to help clarify who's who.